# How to create an ASP.NET Web Forms Application in .NET v3.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a new Web Forms project to an existing solution. However, when I choose .NET 3.5, the only option available to me is ASP.NET Empty Web Application, there is no choice of creating a WebForms app.

If I choose > v4.5 then it gives me the option.

How should a WebForms application be created under .NET 3.5?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @codenheim I have tried in 2015 and 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With 2015 you can create the ASP.NET Empty project, then use "Add Web Form" from the project menu.

[image]

2. Another option is to install VS 2013. I use VS 2013 through 2017 on the same computer, and the latest version that lets me create a .NET 3.5 WebForms project is 2013. The project template is under "Visual Studio 2012" group under ASP.NET projects.

Its possible that there is a project template pack for 2015/2017 that will give you WebForms and 3.5 but my quick search doesn't show anything.

Comment: Ah great stuff! I have 2013 on my laptop and there is indeed an option to create a new Web Forms project in v3.5.
I'll accept your answer, thanks!